# Finding Contours of an image Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, contour

```
# import the necessary packages
import decimal
import imutils
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load the image, convert it to grayscale, and blur it slightly
image = cv2.imread("hand.jpg",0)

# threshold the image, then perform a series of erosions +
# dilations to remove any small regions of noise
thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 45, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, None, iterations=2)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)

# find contours in thresholded image, then grab the largest one
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
size = len(c);

refer_point = (207,130)

data = np.genfromtxt("data.txt", delimiter=',')

X = data[:,][:,0]

Y = data[:,][:,1]

for i in range(0,size):
    dist1= (((abs(207-X))**2)+((abs(130-Y))**2))**(1.0/2.0)

dist3 = round(dist1,2)
print dist3

plt.plot([dist3])

plt.show()
```

I am working on the above code. The code was executed perfectly but the contour points of the image were completely wrong. I observed this error after plotting the graph. Help me on this issue.

Comment: What is the input image and the output of this code snippet ?

Comment: They are images and I cannot attach any images in comment line.

Comment: Then upload them and provide links here

Comment: @AnanthReddy edit your post and upload the image.

Comment: You can upload your image by editing your post. Or did you find your solution??

Answer (score 0):

1) If there is no kernel specified for erosion and dilation, the image does not change. Try them with a kernel.

```
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)
```

2) `cnts` contains the points ((x,y) tuples) on the contour found. `size` is only the number of points on that contour. You acquire the size of it and do not process the points, instead you read a data file and plot something totally different. To properly see the contours, try the following after findContours:

```
# Load the image in color
image = cv2.imread("hand.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
# Draw the contours
cv2.drawContours(image, cnts, -1, (0,255,0), 3)
# Show the image with the contours
cv2.imshow("contours",image)
```

Then try to relate your data file with the contour points.